# how to manipulate with WF4 and ASP.NET threading

Tags: asp.net, workflow-foundation-4

Currently i have an ASP.NET webform application which collaborate with my custom workflow.
I am facing the timing problem of the thread between the httpcontext from ASP.NET and activity context(NativeActivityContext).

My workflow having persistence ability which implement the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore.

Code below is one of the activities inside my workflow, it's doing something like page navigation and return the desired page's url by the extension(PageNavigationExtension).

```
protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
{

    string bookmarkName = this.BookmarkName.Get(context);
    string urlPage = this.UrlPage.Get(context);
    bool createBookmark = this.CreateBookmark.Get(context);



    if (urlPage == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            string.Format("UrlPage {0}: UrlPage can't be null",
                          this.DisplayName), "UrlPage");
    }
    if (bookmarkName == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            string.Format("Bookmark {0}: BookmarkName can't be null",
                          this.DisplayName), "Bookmark");
    }
    innerExecute(context);
    if (createBookmark)
        context.CreateBookmark(bookmarkName, new BookmarkCallback(ResumerBookmark)); ;
}

private void innerExecute(NativeActivityContext context) {
    PageNavigationExtension extension =
            context.GetExtension<PageNavigationExtension>();
    if (extension != null)
    {
        extension.Url = UrlPage.Get(context);
        extension.ObjToReturn = ObjToReturn.Get(context);
    }

}

void ResumeBookmark(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object state)
{
    bool action = (bool)state;


    if (action == true) {
        PageNavigationExtension extension =
            context.GetExtension<PageNavigationExtension>();
        if (extension != null)
        {
            extension.Url = UrlPage.Get(context);
            extension.ObjToReturn = ObjToReturn.Get(context);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        PageNavigationExtension extension = context.GetExtension<PageNavigationExtension>();
        context.SetValue(base.Result, action);
        context.SetValue(ObjToReturn, extension.ObjToReturn);
    }
}
```

This part shown below is part of my ASPX page, which resume to the activity(code shown above).

```
 public string directNavigate(string bMarkName) {
    WorkflowApplication workflow = GetWorkflow(null);
    workflow.Load(this.WorkflowID);
    workflow.ResumeBookmark(bMarkName, true);

    return pageNaviExtension.Url;
}
```

The problem occur during i resume the bookmark in my "directNavigate" function, the activity context is not calling the "`ResumeBookmark`" BookmarkCallback delegate, which until the line of the "`return pageNaviExtension.Url;`", the acititycontext thread just go to the line "`bool action = (bool)state;`" of my "`ResumeBookmark`" BookmarkCallback  delegate.

In short which mean i can't get the page url return by my activity during the line of "`return pageNaviExtension.Url;`" and at the end the thread for the HttpContext for my ASPX page exit the "`directNavigate`" function without the page url.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Found a similar question asked in msdn forum

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/dca30678-9b26-4fe0-b347-f12a702c8e62

which use the SynchronizationContext explicitly stop the HttpContext .

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution which is the AutoResetEvent come into.

During the workflowapplication initialization ,i add the WorkflowApplication.Unloaded delegate to signal the

`AutoResetEvent` (`wfApp.Unloaded = (a) => { waitHandler.Set(); };`)

and while resuming the bookmark, explicitly call the `AutoResetEvent.WaitOne();`,

where it block the HttpContext to continue running until my workflow is unloaded or completed and return out the result.

```
workflow.ResumeBookmark(bMarkName, true);
AutoResetEvent.WaitOne();`
```